# Simple Hello World PHP extension could not be executed

Tags: php, c++, php-extension, php-cpp

I am trying to run simple Hello World PHP extension, but after make & install extension and when I want to run test script I am experiencing following issue:

```
P Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/skeleton.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/skeleton.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3Php9ExtensionD1Ev in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/skeleton.ini
```

My `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <phpcpp.h>
#include <iostream>

void helloWorld (Php::Parameters &params)
{
    std::string name=params[0];
    std::cout<<"Hello "<<name<<"!"<<std::endl;
}

extern "C" {

    PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() 
    {
        static Php::Extension extension("skeleton", "1.0");
        extension.add("helloWorld", helloWorld);
        return extension;
    }
}
```

And here is my test script:

```
<?php
echo helloWorld('Ben');
```

I have been inspired by this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/

Could you help me with this one? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have dynamic extension enabled? Do you run the script from cli? do you see your extension loaded if you run "php -i | grep skeleton"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you should use:

```
Php::out << "Hello " << name << "!" << std::endl;
```

instead of

```
std::cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << std::endl;
```

**std::cout** produces some errors in my extensions.

Vinicius

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error until I saw this ticket on PHP-CPP's repo: https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/issues/180

Turns out my issue was that I followed someone else's advice that I should replace the contents of the `/zend/` dir (in the PHP-CPP lib) with the contents of PHP's source code (that I got from php.net).

Once I rolled back the contents of `/zend/` to be the same as what PHP-CPP provides, the problem went away.